# Считать данные с сайта

Tags: java, html

такой вопрос. В программе передается ссылка и нужно с неё считать информацию, и вывести на экран. Вот пример ссылки: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiev"

Код который считывает данные с сайта:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiev");
    try {
        LineNumberReader reader =
                new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String string = reader.readLine();
        while (string != null) {
            System.out.println(string);
            string = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Как я понял, мы получили HTML страницы. Как нам преобразовать в обычный текст, что бы мы могли отобразить на экран? 
Или как нам лучше это сделать?

Comment: Весь текст? Или текст каких-то конкретных блоков? При отображении какое-то форматирование необходимо?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Ну было бы очень круто что бы начальное определение и весь текст по содержанию. Но хотя бы только определение. Насчет форматирования безразлично, мне для себя. Главное что бы сделать. Последний шаг остался

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `html` парсер.

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, мы считываем весь текст что есть. А как нам указать что нам нужно именно отдельный участок текста. К примеру, только определение про страну и все